# Create a table with sums using dynamic sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

The values I need to select dynamically are dates, and thus change (i.e. weekly or monthly). I would like to know how to do this using the  "EXEC" function in TSQL (SQL Server 2008)

Table Regis has 4 columns, and data similar to this (there are 90k rows):

```
Holder     Period       State  Ttl
Dell       2011-12-31   CA     5
Dell       2012-01-31   PA     7
Sony       2011-11-30   TX     8
Sony       2013-02-28   FL     20
```

The total is the total "sales" in that state for the month ending on that date. This sales data spans 14 months. However, it may grow to 20 months. Also, the dates will change as time goes on, because it is rolling months. I want to just get the State total deals, with the Periods as columns.

I know that removing the Holder and using Group by with SUM, will do this horizontally. I also know that with knowledge of all the Periods I can use pivot. However, I'd like the Period to be the columns and want to do this via dynamic SQL, because there are other things I need to learn dynamic SQL for. Thanks for your help.

end result should be like

```
state    2011-11-30  2011-12-31... 2013-02-28
CA       100         205           78
WA       90          159           62
CO       16          654           31
TX       87          321           205
NY       54          45            415
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will need to do a dynamic pivot since your column names are unknown and the quantity of them is also unknown.  I do something similar in the code below.  The COALESCE is most of the magic, as it builds the list to pivot on.  "SysCode" in my example would be the equivelant of your "Period" column.

```
--Pull the data set

DECLARE
    @Query NVARCHAR(4000)

INSERT INTO 
    #Rates

SELECT 
    CAST(mrc.StartDay AS DATE) [Start Date],
    CAST(mrc.EndDay AS DATE) [End Date],
    dpe.NCCDayPart [Daypart],
    dpe.NCCDayPartDescription [Description],
    mrc.Network,
    ru.SysCode,
    mrc.Rate

FROM 
    minimumratecards mrc
    LEFT JOIN DaypartExtension dpe
        ON mrc.DayPartSequence = dpe.Sequence
        AND dpe.Division = 'CAMC'
    LEFT JOIN #RetailUnit ru
        ON mrc.RetailUnitCode = ru.RetailUnit


WHERE
    mrc.MinimumRateCardID = @MinimumRateCardID



--Get a distinct list of syscodes that were returned    
SELECT DISTINCT
    Syscode

INTO
    #Syscodes

FROM
    #Rates



--Format the syscode list into a string to be used in the pivot table
SELECT 
    @Cols = COALESCE(@Cols + ',[' + SysCode + ']',
                         '[' + SysCode + ']')
FROM    
    #Syscodes

ORDER BY 
    SysCode



--Pivot the data
SET @Query = 
    N'SELECT 
        [Start Date],
        [End Date],
        [Daypart],
        [Description],
        [Network], '+
        @Cols +'
    FROM
    (SELECT 
        [Start Date],
        [End Date],
        [Daypart],
        [Description],
        [Network],
        [Rate],
        [SysCode]
    FROM    #Rates AS t1) p
    PIVOT
        (
        MAX([Rate])
        FOR [SysCode] IN
        ( '+
        @Cols +' )
        ) AS pvt
        ORDER BY [Network];'


EXECUTE(@Query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server you can use the PIVOT function to transform your rows into columns.

Before jumping into a dynamic version it is easier to see how the code is set up for limited or static values.  For your data, you will use:

```
select *
from
(
  select period, state, ttl
  from regis
) d
pivot
(
  sum(ttl)
  for period in ([2011-11-30], [2011-12-31], [2013-02-28])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f46b6/1).

You will need to create a list of the distinct `period` values that will be used in the pivot.  The code to create this list will be similar to :

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Period) 
                    from regis
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

The code that you will use to create the dynamic SQL is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Period) 
                    from regis
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT state, ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select period, state, ttl
                from regis
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(ttl)
                for period in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```